# Visual Studio Test Controller Configuration Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am configuring Test Controller but I am getting error "Failed to Configure TFS Team Project Collection". I am using the same service account which I assign to TFS admin console as well I also given the add same user in my default collection of TFS but still I got error

below is the Error Log of the same error

---

```
Configuration started on 2013/07/05, 19:34:40.
OS Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
Executable version : 11.0.60610.1

I, 2013/07/05, 19:34:40.927, Listing controller configurations
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.511, IsValidTfsConnectionModified: Controller service in not installed. Returning True
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.584, Controller configuration update pack details :
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.587, User name : Administrator
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.587, Change service account : True
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.587, Change load test database server : True
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.587, Loadtest database server : 
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.587, Change TFS Registration : True
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.588, TFC Uri : hp//uto2008r2-sc:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.588, Change Port : False
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.588, Port : -1
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.601, Validating configuration updates.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.620, Validated configuration updates.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.622, Validating user name and password.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.635, Validated user name and password.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.817, Starting firewall configuration...
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:48.866, IsPortExceptionEnabled: Checking for port exception for port 6901 in firewall profile STANDARD
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.013, IsPortExceptionEnabled: Checking for port exception for port 6901 in firewall profile DOMAIN
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.029, IsPortExceptionEnabled: Checking for port exception for port 6901 in firewall profile CURRENT
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.047, BaseConfig: AddFirewallExceptionIfRequired: Firewall exception already enabled for port 6901.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.047, No change to the firewall setting as the firewall exception was already enabled for the application 'Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller'.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.239, BaseConfig: AddFirewallExceptionIfRequired: Firewall exception already enabled for service File and Printer Sharing.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.240, No change to the firewall setting as the firewall exception was already enabled for the service 'File and Printer Sharing'.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.241, IsPortExceptionEnabled: Checking for port exception for port 80 in firewall profile STANDARD
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.273, IsPortExceptionEnabled: Checking for port exception for port 80 in firewall profile DOMAIN
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.307, IsPortExceptionEnabled: Checking for port exception for port 80 in firewall profile CURRENT
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.338, BaseConfig: AddFirewallExceptionIfRequired: Firewall exception already enabled for port 80.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.340, No change to the firewall setting as the firewall exception was already enabled for the application 'Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller - Test Agent Download Service'.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.345, Configured firewall exceptions for: 'Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller', 'File and Printer Sharing', 'Microsoft Visual Studio Test Controller - Test Agent Download Service'.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.348, Creating event sources VSTTController 
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.348, Creating event sources VSTTController 
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.348, Event source VSTTController already exists.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.349, Adding event source for event logging
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.350, ResetForceGuestKey : Getting the value of ForceGuest key
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.350, ResetForceGuestKey : The value of ForceGuest key is 0
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.363, Configuring local groups...
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.364, Started checking the status of controller groups.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.635, Found that group TeamTestAgentService exists /? True.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.639, Found that group TeamTestControllerUsers exists /? True.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.645, Found that group TeamTestControllerAdmins exists /? True.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.646, Built In Administrators Name WinNT://BUILTIN/Administrators
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.681, Administrators group is part of TeamTestControllerAdmins group
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.681, Found that controller groups already exist.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.684, No change to local groups as they are already configured.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.708, ControllerConfiguration: Registered the url hp://+:80/AgentInstallerService for user UTO2008R2-SC\Administrator
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.711, Starting service configuration...
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.711, Started checking the status of controller service VSTTController.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.713, Controller service VSTTController is not installed, attempting to install it now.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.717, Installing service ServicenName=VSTTController, DisplayName=Visual Studio Test Controller, Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\QTController.exe, Description=Provides Distributed Test Engine controller services, userName=UTO2008R2-SC\administrator, Dependencies=System.String[]  
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.718, Dependency string is dhcp  
V, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.785, Service installed with return code 109457936
V, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.785, Updating the description Provides Distributed Test Engine controller services of the service VSTTController.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.802, Installed Controller service VSTTController.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.813, Found binary Sid 'System.Byte[]' for account UTO2008R2-SC\administrator 
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.816, Granted LogonAsService permission to controller service account UTO2008R2-SC\administrator.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.818, UpdateServiceStartTime : Getting the value of ServiceStartTimeout key
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.818, UpdateServiceStartTime : The value of ServiceStartTimeout key is 600000
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.819, DisableLocalAccountToken : Creating the key DisableLocalAccountToken and setting the value to 1
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.821, Configured service successfully.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.831, Configuring ACL...
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.849, Granting permission on file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\QTControllerConfig.xml to account UTO2008R2-SC\administrator
I, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.865, Granted permission on file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\QTControllerConfig.xml to account UTO2008R2-SC\administrator
V, 2013/07/05, 19:35:49.867, AddAccessToDirectory: started: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE, rights: Write, Read
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.702, AddAccessToDirectory: completed
I, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.703, Configured ACL successfully.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.711, Adding service account UTO2008R2-SC\administrator to controller users group 
I, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.838, Added service account UTO2008R2-SC\administrator to controller users group 
I, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.839, Found that service VSTTController is installed and its current status is Stopped
I, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.840, Starting service VSTTController
I, 2013/07/05, 19:36:28.842, Starting service VSTTController whose current status is Stopped
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:29.422, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state StartPending.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:34.437, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:39.440, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:44.441, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:49.442, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:54.442, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:36:59.443, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:04.444, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:09.694, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:14.695, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:19.944, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:24.945, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:30.195, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:35.195, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:40.197, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:45.197, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:50.199, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:37:55.199, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:00.200, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:05.200, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:10.204, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:15.455, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:20.455, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:25.705, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:30.706, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:35.708, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:40.708, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:45.958, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:51.209, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:38:56.210, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:01.211, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:06.213, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:11.237, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:16.238, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:21.240, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:26.242, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:31.242, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:36.243, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:41.246, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:46.246, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:51.249, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:39:56.261, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:01.266, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:06.271, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:11.409, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:16.499, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:21.507, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:26.508, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:31.525, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:36.526, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:41.528, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:46.529, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:51.532, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:40:56.536, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:01.786, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:06.790, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:11.795, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:16.797, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:21.797, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:26.805, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:31.805, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:36.807, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:41.808, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:46.809, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:51.810, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:41:56.811, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:01.811, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:07.061, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:12.062, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:17.062, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:22.312, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:27.562, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:32.563, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:37.565, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:42.567, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:47.570, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:52.570, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:42:57.571, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:02.577, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:07.577, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:12.577, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:17.578, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:22.580, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:27.580, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:32.582, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:37.582, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:42.585, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:47.835, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:53.085, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:43:58.087, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:03.336, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:08.337, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:13.338, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:18.587, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:23.588, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:28.590, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:33.591, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:38.591, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:43.592, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:48.594, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:53.595, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:44:58.845, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:03.845, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:08.847, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:13.847, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:18.848, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:24.098, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:29.098, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:34.101, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:39.102, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:44.103, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:49.106, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:54.107, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:45:59.357, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:04.360, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:09.610, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:14.610, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:19.615, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:24.615, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:29.615, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
E, 2013/07/05, 19:46:29.616, Timedout while waiting for service Visual Studio Test Controller to go to state Running. Current status is Stopped
I, 2013/07/05, 19:46:29.616, IsValidTfsConnectionModified: exception occurred, returning false
I, 2013/07/05, 19:46:29.625, Configuring TFS Team Project Collection. This may take few minutes...
I, 2013/07/05, 19:46:29.632, Starting service VSTTController
I, 2013/07/05, 19:46:29.633, Starting service VSTTController whose current status is Stopped
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:30.129, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state StartPending.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:35.129, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:40.131, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:45.381, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:50.630, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:46:55.880, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:25.756, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.757, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
E, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.757, Timedout while waiting for service Visual Studio Test Controller to go to state Running. Current status is Stopped
E, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.780, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Could not complete operation as the timeout expired.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus endStatus, TimeSpan timeOut, ServiceController service, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener, ConfigurationMessage message)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services._StartService(ServiceController serviceController, Int32 timeout, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener, ConfigurationMessage progressMessage)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services.StartService(String serviceName, Int32 timeout, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener, ConfigurationMessage progressMessage)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.BaseConfiguration.EnsureServiceIsRunning(String serviceName, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.ChangeTfsRegistration(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
E, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.782, Failed to configure TFS Team Project Collection.
I, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.789, Configuration of lab service user started
I, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.791, Starting service VSTTController
I, 2013/07/05, 19:56:30.791, Starting service VSTTController whose current status is Stopped
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:31.266, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state StartPending.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:36.268, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:41.270, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:46.273, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:51.276, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 19:56:56.525, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
V, 2013/07/05, 20:06:31.879, Service 'Visual Studio Test Controller' is in state Stopped.
E, 2013/07/05, 20:06:31.879, Timedout while waiting for service Visual Studio Test Controller to go to state Running. Current status is Stopped
E, 2013/07/05, 20:06:31.880, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Could not complete operation as the timeout expired.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus endStatus, TimeSpan timeOut, ServiceController service, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener, ConfigurationMessage message)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services._StartService(ServiceController serviceController, Int32 timeout, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener, ConfigurationMessage progressMessage)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.Services.StartService(String serviceName, Int32 timeout, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener, ConfigurationMessage progressMessage)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.BaseConfiguration.EnsureServiceIsRunning(String serviceName, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.ConfigureLabServiceUserAccount(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
E, 2013/07/05, 20:06:31.911, Got Exception : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ConfigToolException: Configuration of lab service user failed
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.ConfigureLabServiceUserAccount(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.Configure(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate ProgressUpdateCB)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ControllerConfigUI.ControllerConfigUI.ConfigureWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
I, 2013/07/05, 20:06:31.911, Work completed for GetConfiguration() call : got out of turn error
E, 2013/07/05, 20:06:31.912, Configuration of lab service user failed
```

Comment: Were you able to proceed? What permissions does the user attempting to configure the controller have on TFS?

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similiar issue in the past.
Check your event viewer.

If you see an issue like the one posted below, you should check what process uses port 80 and kill it/disable its listener.

> (QTController.exe, PID 720, Thread 5) Unable to initialize the
>   agentinstallerservice endpoint properly. Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: HTTP could not
>   register URL http:/+:80/AgentInstallerService/ because TCP port 80 is
>   being used by another application. --->
>   System.Net.HttpListenerException: The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process    at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()    at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.Start()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener
>   channelListener)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback
>   selectTransportManagerCallback)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.AgentInstall.AgentInstallServiceBase.Start()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Controller.ControllerServiceBase.StartAgentInstallerService(ControllerConfiguration
>   configuration)